# How to pass a django model to a javascript function

Tags: javascript, json, django, function, serialization

I have a javascript function that needs some variables (about 10) from my view. I don't need to call again the variables once the page is loaded. I could give them using a context dict, like below, but maybe is possible to do better.

My `models.py`:

```
class Mymodel(models.Model):
    my_field1 = #
    my_field2 = #
    ...
    my_field10 = #
```

My `views.py`:

```
def myview(request):
    context_dict={}
    context_dict['myfield1'] = Mymodel.objects.get(id=1).myfield1
    context_dict['myfield2'] = Mymodel.objects.get(id=1).myfield2
    context_dict['myfield10'] = Mymodel.objects.get(id=1).myfield10
```

My `template.html`:

```
...
<script>
  <!--
  window.onpageshow = function() {
    my_function( '{{ myfield1 }}', '{{ myfield2 }}', ..., '{{ myfield10 }}' );
  };
  -->
</script>
...
```

My `javascript.js`:

```
function my_function(myfield1, myfield2, ..., myfield10) {
  //code
}
```

These variables are the fields of a model, so i just need to pass the model istance. How can I do that? It's some time I work on it and I think I should use `serialize` but I don't understand how...

My `template.html`:

```
...
<script>
  <!--
  window.onpageshow = function() {
    my_function( serializers.serialize("json", {{ mymodelistance }} ));
  };
  -->
</script>
...
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: `serializers.serialize` is Django code. You need to call it in your Django view.

Comment: And you haven't needed to put protective comment tags in scripts for at least 15 years.

Answer (score 0):

To access your model fields you can directly use angular js ($http.get) method and assign it to the script's variable as per your needs. But for this you would have to make use of Django Tastypie which will allow you to serialize the data which will be then accessible.

This answer is valid if and only if you don't want to do processing on the data in view.

Even if you would like to process the data before saving you can use tastypie hydration.

Comment: I think to be asking something very basilar so I would prefer to not use apps or frameworks

Answer (score 0):

So here my solution:

My `views.py`:

```
def myview(request):
    context_dict={}
    mymodelistance = Mymodel.objects.filter(id=1)
    mymodelistance_json = serializers.serialize('json', mymodelistance)
    context_dict['mymodelistance'] = mymodelistance_json
```

My `template.html`:

```
...
<script>
  window.onpageshow = function() {
    my_function( '{{ mymodelistance|safe }}' );
  };
</script>
...
```

My `javascript.js`:

```
function my_function(mymodelistance) {
  var mymodelistance_obj = JSON.parse(flag)
  var myfield1 = mymodelistance_obj[0].fields.myfield1;
  var myfield2 = mymodelistance_obj[0].fields.myfield2;
  ...
  //code
}
```